# Record Video on Background Android 4.0

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-service, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am trying to record video on the background with the use of *Activity* and *Service*, however I can't make it work. The application just shows the buttons then it closes. I'm running it on a Galaxy SII Android 4.0.3, the following are the errors and source codes.

LogCat

```
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/MediaRecorder(28177): start failed: -19
04-24 22:27:10.158: D/AndroidRuntime(28177): Shutting down VM
04-24 22:27:10.158: W/dalvikvm(28177): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c511f8)
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.transfertofile.RecorderService@41519328 with Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.transfertofile/.RecorderService }: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2388)
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1222)
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at com.example.transfertofile.RecorderService.startRecording(RecorderService.java:107)
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at com.example.transfertofile.RecorderService.onStartCommand(RecorderService.java:48)
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2371)
04-24 22:27:10.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    ... 10 more
```

CameraRecorder.java

```
public class CameraRecorder extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume() ;
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        Log.v(TAG, "onresume");
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // do something

                if (mPreviewRunning) {
                    mPreviewRunning = !mPreviewRunning;
                    stopService(new Intent(CameraRecorder.this, RecorderService.class));
                    Log.v(TAG, "running");
                    finish();
                }
                else {
                    mPreviewRunning = !mPreviewRunning;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CameraRecorder.this, RecorderService.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startService(intent);
                    Log.v(TAG, "notrunning");
                    finish();
                }
             }
        };
        worker.schedule(task, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

RecorderService.java

```
public class RecorderService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "RecorderService";
private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
private static Camera mServiceCamera;
private boolean mRecordingStatus;
private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.v(TAG, "oncreate");
    mRecordingStatus = false;
    mServiceCamera = CameraRecorder.mCamera;
    mSurfaceView = CameraRecorder.mSurfaceView;
    mSurfaceHolder = CameraRecorder.mSurfaceHolder;

    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onstartcom");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    if (mRecordingStatus == false)
        startRecording();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.v(TAG, "ondestroy");
    stopRecording();
    mRecordingStatus = false;

    super.onDestroy();
}   



public boolean startRecording(){
    try {
        Log.v(TAG, "startrecording");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mServiceCamera = Camera.open();
        Camera.Parameters params = mServiceCamera.getParameters();
        mServiceCamera.setParameters(params);
        Camera.Parameters p = mServiceCamera.getParameters();

        final List<Size> listSize = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Size mPreviewSize = listSize.get(2);
        Log.v(TAG, "use: width = " + mPreviewSize.width 
                    + " height = " + mPreviewSize.height);
        p.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        p.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP);
        mServiceCamera.setParameters(p);
        Log.v(TAG, "setparams");

        try {
            mServiceCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mServiceCamera.startPreview();
            Log.v(TAG, "setpreview");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage() + "woo");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mServiceCamera.unlock();
        Log.v(TAG, "camunlock");

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mServiceCamera);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/video.mp4");
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());

        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        mMediaRecorder.start(); 

        mRecordingStatus = true;

        return true;
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public void stopRecording() {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Recording Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try {
        mServiceCamera.reconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mMediaRecorder.stop();
    mMediaRecorder.reset();

    mServiceCamera.stopPreview();
    mMediaRecorder.release();

    mServiceCamera.release();
    mServiceCamera = null;
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.transfertofile"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.transfertofile.CameraRecorder"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.transfertofile.RecorderService"></service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Source codes from: https://github.com/pickerweng/CameraRecorder

Answer (score 0):

Please add below permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
```